# Why should I use a closing bracket in this?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have some code which I could not compile it yet. The compiler says there should be a closing bracket, but I can't see a reason for this or place to put it. This is my code:

```
#include "Player.h"

Player(std::string val){
    set_Name(val);
    set_Alliance("NONE");
    set_LastUpdate();
}

Player(std::string val, std::string ally){
    set_Name(val);
    set_Alliance(ally);
    set_LastUpdate();
}
```

I have  included in Player.h

This is the error:

```
error: expected ')' before 'val'
```

This is the prototype for constructor:

```
Player(std::string);
```

I am using GNU GCC compiler, under linux(ubuntu)

Comment: Did you miss to `#include <string>` actually?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/CFe4JS (after adding some things to make it compile)

Comment: Are you sure it is that line, and not one of the lines below?

Comment: @Almo yes, that's what i want. 

I have tried to start a new project to see if compiler got confused about something. But still same. It is insists about that bracket.

Comment: and yes, @πάνταῥεῖ i have included <string>

Comment: @EvanCarslake positive. I mean there is only 2 lines which involves 'val'. Second one obvious, so...

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nothing more to say.

Comment: @mertyeniay Your .cpp file should look like [this](http://ideone.com/J7JIau), i.e. prefix both constructors belonging to the `Player` class with `Player::`. (So the compiler knows that they are the `Player` constructors and not some other functions.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing the class name from constructor outside the class definition. Try this:

```
Player::Player(std::string val){  // constructor outside class definition
    set_Name(val);
    set_Alliance("NONE");
    set_LastUpdate();
}
```

Unverified speculation: With your current code, compiler sees *Player(symbol1 symbol2)* and takes that as creating object of class *Player*, and first thing it fails to understand is seeing two symbols as constructor argument, and gives a somewhat misleading error about that.

Comment: Hahaha! I missed that. :D

Comment: It's only in header file. So thats not the problem. Let me edit and put all code.

Comment: @mertyeniay There's no "only in header file". Header files are just text which is "copypasted" to the .cpp file by preprosessor. Compiler makes no distinction between code in a .h and in a .cpp file.

Comment: ok, now i see. Mistakes were made. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

When you define methods, constructor, destructor etc. outside of the class, remember to tell the compiler that this belongs to the class using the class name following the scope operator `::` and the name of the method, constructor, destructor etc with the matching parameters.

As a small example:

```
class Phone {
    string number;
public:
    string get_num();
    void set_num(string const &num) { number = num; }
};

// Pay attention to this:
// we tell the compiler that get_num belongs to class Phone
string Phone::get_num()
{
    return number;
}

int main()
{
    Phone p;
    p.set_num("123");
    cout << p.get_num() << endl;
}
```